# Activity A moveTaskToBack() and startAcitivty B, The A onDestory is called

Tags: android

I have two activities, there's launchMode both are singleTask.

App start -> MainActivity start -> VideoActivity

For some reason, the VideoActivity needs hide behind and stays alive(reshow the activity in any time).

So, I call moveTaskBack(true) and startActivity(MainActivity) in VideoActivity(I did't call finish()),but for some how, onDestroy called in VideoActivity.

Did I do something wrong, any help please?

Comment: I call startActivity(MainActivity) add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT